# Minimum 5 character match in sql-server table columns(containing string)

Tags: php, sql-server

Consider two sql-server table columns

```
Column1                Column2
mr white james bond    james cameron  
gordon ramsay          Harry Gordon Selfridge
```

I need to select these tables are equal by comparing 5 letters match in name. Example

- Name `mr white james bond` and `james cameron` contains common five
  letter word `james`.
- Name `gordon ramsay` and `Harry Gordon Selfridge` contains common
  five
     letter word `gordo`.

Is it possible ?.
I can match **first** 5 characters using this

```
 SELECT * FROM table1 A
 INNER JOIN table2 B ON UPPER(SUBSTRING(A.name,1,5))=UPPER(SUBSTRING(B.name,1,5))
```

But can't match all 5 characters possibilities.

Comment: read out the article : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636051/how-to-join-two-tables-based-on-substring-values-of-fields

Comment: @HappyCoding Thanks for your answer. But, I don't have any predefined values of substring START and END - as your reference article link.

Comment: You could use `A.name like '%'+substring(B.name,1,5)+'%'` to solve the substring part in A. Not sure how to deal with B having the substring anywhere though.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks. In my case, the substring start,end values not always (1,5). It should be dynamic based on possibilities of 5 character in name string. Example: `mr white james bond ` will be in substring like `mr whi` , `r whit`, `white`, `hite j`...`james`,etc... and matches the `james`.

Answer (score 1):

Try concatenating both the strings.

```
SELECT A.name, B.name FROM table1 A
INNER JOIN table2 B ON '%' + UPPER(SUBSTRING(A.name,1,5)) + '%' LIKE '%' + UPPER(SUBSTRING(B.name,1,5)) + '%'
ORDER BY A.id
```