# SQL: Edit data before join

Tags: sql, oracle

ORACLE: I am trying to LEFT OUTER JOIN a table, on PART column. 
First Part Column is formatted as following: "XXXXXXXX". 
Column  number two is formatted as following: "ABCXXXXXXXX". 
I want to exclude "ABC" before "XXXXXXXX". is there a formula for doing this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use substring. Have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28636051/how-to-join-two-tables-based-on-substring-values-of-fields

Comment: What is your actual database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)?  "SQL" is just a language, not an implementation.

Comment: Tough luck. You shouldn't have run into this issue of your database was properly designed.

Comment: I am with jarlh here. If the separate parts of the string are essential for querying the data, then these should be stored separately. You may want to consider fixing the data model, rather than creating queries that deal with it.

Comment: How do you mean fixing the data model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join using the substring on the second column starting with the fourth character, e.g.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
     ON t1.PART = SUBSTR(t2.PART, 4);
```

Comment: I tried this, but I get error message from Oracle; ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier

Comment: @MS_90 You are either using MySQL or Oracle.  In either case, use `SUBSTR`, q.v. my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `LIKE`, is an operator used to search for a specified pattern in a column.

Try something like this:

```
column2 LIKE '%' + column1
```

for mysql you need use `concat('%', column1)`

It finds any values that end with column1 value

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.PART = 'ABC' || t1.PART ;
```

This allows Oracle to use an index on `t2.PART`.  For an `INNER JOIN` this would not matter.  But in a `LEFT JOIN`, `table1` is going to be scanned anyway.  This may allow Oracle to use the an index on `table2(PART)`.

Or more generally:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.PART LIKE '___' || t1.PART ;
```